# How to inline a destructurer

Tags: javascript

I have the following function, I would like to know if there is a way to make it in one line without using the curly braces.

```js
const nameAttr = attributes => {
  const [name, , ,] = attributes;
  return name;
}

console.log(nameAttr(['a', 1, 10]));
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't need `, , ,` in the array. Extra elements are simply ignored when destructuring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Destructure the first element of the input

```js
const nameAttr = ([name]) => name;

console.log(nameAttr(['a', 1, 10]))
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Indexing First element

```js
const f = e => e[0]
console.log(f(['a', 1, 10]))
```

#### Destructuring

Extra elements are ignored

```js
const f = ([e]) => e
console.log(f(['a', 1, 10]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by getting the first entry from the array:

```js
const nameAttr = attributes => attributes[0]

console.log(nameAttr(['a', 1, 10]))
```